# how to read data from google drive using Colaboratory (google)

Tags: python, google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to Colaboratory and would like setup a small project which is stored on my google drive. On my google drive, I create a folder 'TheProject', where I created two folders: 'code' and 'data'. I the folder 'code' I created a new colab notebook and I have several data sets in 'data' folder.

**QUESTION**

How to read data into colab notebook from a folder on the google drive?
 For example:

```
data = pd.read_excel('SOME_PATH/TheProject/data/my_data.xlsx')
```

where `SOME_PATH` should indicate how to get to the main folder 'TheProject' and read data from 'data' folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on your file on Google Drive and get its sharable link. from that link you'll extract the file id.

```
! pip install pydrive
# these classes allow you to request the Google drive API
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive 
from google.colab import auth 
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
file_id = '<your_file_id>'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
# allows you to temporarily load your file in the notebook VM

# assume the file is called file.csv and it's located at the root of your drive
downloaded.GetContentFile('file.csv')
```

Once you hit these commands you will be prompted a link that asks you to grant permission to Google Drive. It'll give you a token that you must type in a text box.

Now you're ready to load your file:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```